# Counting time in Outlook-AddIn C#

Tags: c#, time, outlook-addin

i am currently writing an AddIn for Outlook 2010, using Visual Studio 2015, that automatically saves mails to certain folders.

I want to implement a Method/Event that triggers everytime a new timestamp is reached.

For Example:

When the Startup-Method runs the first time it should save the current time and add 2 Hours.

Is there a way to trigger an Event once the saved Time is reached?
What would be the best way to do that?

Comment: You can write a console program and use window schedule to trigger it. Or search Topshelf I use this to write a schedule console.

Comment: Thx for your answer.